# Plot a gridded surface plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm a beginner to R and I am trying to plot a surface plot on a specific grid. Basically I have a data-set of points from across the UK containing the longitude, latitude and amount of rainfall for a particular day. Using the following code I can plot this data onto a UK map:

```
dat <- read.table("~jan1.csv", header=T, sep=",")
names(dat) <- c("gauge", "date", "station", "mm", "lat", "lon", "location", "county",    "days")
library(fields)
quilt.plot(cbind(dat$lon,dat$lat),dat$mm)
world(add=TRUE)
```

So far so good. I can also perform a thin plate spline interpolation (TPS) using:

```
fit <- Tps(cbind(dat$lon, dat$lat), dat$mm, scale.type="unscaled")
```

and then I can do a surface plot at a grid scale of my choice e.g.:

```
surface (fit, nx=100, ny=100)
```

This effectively gives me a gridded data plot at the resolution of 100*100.

Following help from another user I can now extract this data in a grid by using:

```
xvals <- seq(-10, 4, len=20)
yvals <- seq(49, 63, len=20)
griddf <- expand.grid(xvals, yvals)
griddg <- predict(fit, x=as.matrix(griddf) )
```

What I would like to do now is plot the surface plot again using the same grid as the predict function (i.e. same as xvals and yvals) as above?  Do you know how I can do this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have predicted your new values in `griddg`, you can technically re-interpolate with `Tps` and then proceed with the surface plot and map as before:

#### Example:

```
xvals <- seq(-10, 4, len=20)
yvals <- seq(49, 63, len=20)
griddf <- expand.grid(lon=xvals, lat=yvals)
griddg <- predict(fit, x=as.matrix(griddf) )

dat2 <- cbind(griddf, mm=griddg)
head(dat2)
fit <- Tps(cbind(dat2$lon, dat2$lat), dat2$mm, scale.type="unscaled")
surface (fit, nx=100, ny=100)
world(add=TRUE)
```

For more control over your maps, you could also plot your new grid directly - This is probably more correct in that the above method essentially fits your interpolation `Tps` twice. This method requires some external functions, but you will have more flexibility in your mapping.

```
#option 2
source("matrix.poly.r") #http://menugget.blogspot.de/2012/04/create-polygons-from-matrix.html
source("val2col.R") # http://menugget.blogspot.de/2011/09/converting-values-to-color-levels.html
source("image.scale.R") # http://menugget.blogspot.de/2011/08/adding-scale-to-image-plot.html

#new grid and predition
xvals <- seq(-10, 4, len=100)
yvals <- seq(49, 63, len=100)
griddf <- expand.grid(lon=xvals, lat=yvals)
griddg <- predict(fit, x=as.matrix(griddf) )

#make polygons for new grid, calculate color levels
mat <- matrix(griddg, nrow=length(xvals), ncol=length(yvals))
poly <- matrix.poly(xvals, yvals, z=mat, n=seq(mat))
pal <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "cyan", "yellow", "red"))
COL <- val2col(mat, col=pal(100))

#required packages
library(maps)
library(mapproj)

#plot
png("tmp.png", width=5, height=4, res=400, units="in")
layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=1, ncol=2), widths=c(4,1), heights=4)
par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
map("world", proj="stereographic", orient=c(mean(yvals),mean(xvals),0), par=NULL, t="n", xlim=range(xvals), ylim=range(yvals))
for(i in seq(poly)){
 polygon(mapproject(poly[[i]]), col=COL[i], border=COL[i], lwd=0.3)
}
map("world", proj="stereographic", orient=c(mean(yvals),mean(xvals),0), par=NULL, add=T)
map.grid(col=rgb(0,0,0,0.5), labels=F)
box()

par(mar=c(5,0,5,4))
image.scale(mat, col=pal(100), horiz=FALSE, axes=FALSE, xlab="", ylab="")
axis(4)
mtext("mm", side=4, line=2.5)
box()

dev.off()
```

[image]